# Google Map not showing with Ionic 2 native google-maps plugin cordova android 7

Tags: google-maps, ionic3, cordova-plugins

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

following all the instructions still map no loaded got blank map.

checked it for solution here.

applied all the solutions still not working.

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/TroubleShooting/Blank-Map/README.md

HTML :

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

CSS :

```
page-home {
    #map_canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

ts :

```
    import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapOptions, CameraPosition, MarkerOptions, Marker } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
    import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {
      map: GoogleMap;
      constructor(private gm: GoogleMaps, private platform: Platform) { }
      ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          // this.loadMap();
          setTimeout(this.loadMap.bind(this), 1000);
        });
      }
      getMyLocation() {
        this.map.getMyLocation().then(location => {
          alert('success!');
          alert(JSON.stringify(location));
        }).catch(err => {
          alert('failure!');
          alert(JSON.stringify(location));
        });
      }

  loadMap() {

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
      .then(() => {
        alert('Map is ready!');
        this.map.addMarker({
          title: 'Ionic',
          icon: 'blue',
          animation: 'DROP',
          position: {
            lat: 43.0741904,
            lng: -89.3809802
          }
        })
          .then(marker => {
            marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
              .subscribe(() => {
                alert('clicked');
              });
          });

      });
  }
}
```

Output: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to enable GPS before view will load or to avoid cordova issues you can implement js google map

Answer (score 0):

There is a Google logo at the bottom-left, but the map is empty.
This means your API key is unauthorized.

It seems the device is offline.
You must authorize at least one time through the internet.

And the Google Maps Android API v2 and the Google Maps SDK for iOS are enabled **before** generating the API keys.
Because Google keeps the information which API key allowed what APIs were enabled at generating time.

So, my recommendations are:
1. turn on the device network
2. if it does not work, regenerate the api keys, then reinstall the plugin.

Comment: I'm running it on bluestacks app player and vivo phone. I followed the steps you mentioned. Still it's not working. Also I'm connected to network. My device is online. I've regenerated the api keys twice and enabled maps api before regenerating it. Is there anything else i'm missing to configure?